# automake error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found

Tags: autotools, automake

I am new in autotools, and following this [tutorial](http://markuskimius.wikidot.com/programming:tut:autotools:4). but I could not solve this errors,

```
   $ automake
   configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
   ..
   Makefile.am: error: required file './depcomp' not found
   ..
   /usr/share/automake-1.12/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCC does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
  ..
  /usr/share/automake-1.12/am/depend2.am: error: AMDEP does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
  ..
```

my `configure.ac` file is

```
   # -*- Autoconf -*-
   # Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

   AC_PREREQ([2.69])
   AC_INIT([FULL-PACKAGE-NAME], [VERSION], [BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS])
   AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(hello,1.0)
   AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([config.h.in])
   AM_CONFIG_HEADERS(config.h)

   # Checks for programs.
   AC_PROG_CC

   # Checks for libraries.

   # Checks for header files.
   AC_CHECK_HEADERS([sys/time.h])

   # Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

   # Checks for library functions.
   AC_CHECK_FUNCS([gettimeofday])

   AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
   AC_OUTPUT
```

I checked for solution on Internet, my `configure.ac` looks fine, don't know what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to fix it line by line.

First, your `Makefile.am` required `depcomp`. So, you have to copy it to your folder (for this step you can run `automake --add-missing` so as to add missing files automatically):

```
cp -a /usr/share/automake-X.XX/depcomp .
```

Second, you have to run `aclocal` prior to `automake`:

```
$ aclocal
```

Finally, you can run `automake`:

```
$ automake
$ autoconf
```

Answer (score 31):

Where did you copy&paste your `configure.ac` from?  Whatever that site is, you should remove it from your bookmarks!

You are mixing the new `AC_INIT` way to indicate the package version, with the old `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` way to do the same thing.  Don't do both.  (*Old* and *new* refer to a switch that occurred 10 years ago.)  Starting with Automake 1.13 the old way to call `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` with two arguments is no-longuer supported.

In your case, removing the `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` arguments, and correctly setting the `AC_INIT` arguement to reflect the name and version of your project should be enough.

See [the automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Hello-World) for an up-to-date example of very simple `configure.ac` to start with.

Instead of calling `automake` yourself, just use `autoreconf -vfi` so that it runs all the relevant tools in the right order, and installs the missing files.

Comment: I should look for latest examples.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
autoreconf -i
```

autoreconf will bootstrap a project into a distributable state by adding missing files that are recommended or required.

Comment: See @adl's answer, which is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, updating libtool from 2.2.6 to 2.4.6.
ps: I use the 1.15 version of automake.
Run libtoolize before running aclocal and autoheader.